# problem compiling re_comm

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI I have problem compiling the re_comm package in the roboearth. The problems is shown like this:

```
   [ 83%] Generating ../bin/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.class, ../bin/roboearth/wp5/REClients.class, ../bin/roboearth/wp5/util/Util.class, ../bin/roboearth/wp5/REDummyUploader.class, ../bin/roboearth/wp5/Main.class
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:88: package ros.pkg.vision_srvs.srv does not exist
import ros.pkg.vision_srvs.srv.cop_save;
                              ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp5/Main.java:50: package edu.tum.cs.ias.knowrob.vis.applets does not exist
import edu.tum.cs.ias.knowrob.vis.applets.CommunicationVisApplet; //add
                                         ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:284: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable CommunicationVisApplet
location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.ExportCopModelCallback
                CommunicationVisApplet.visualizeCommunication("Retrieving model from the vision system... \n\nSending: /cop/save "+req.object_id, "", null, "cop.png");
                ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:293: package cop_save does not exist
                ServiceClient<cop_save.Request, cop_save.Response, cop_save> client = n.serviceClient("/cop/save", new ros.pkg.vision_srvs.srv.cop_save());
                                      ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:293: package cop_save does not exist
                ServiceClient<cop_save.Request, cop_save.Response, cop_save> client = n.serviceClient("/cop/save", new ros.pkg.vision_srvs.srv.cop_save());
                                                        ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:293: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class cop_save
location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.ExportCopModelCallback
                ServiceClient<cop_save.Request, cop_save.Response, cop_save> client = n.serviceClient("/cop/save", new ros.pkg.vision_srvs.srv.cop_save());
                                                                   ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:293: package ros.pkg.vision_srvs.srv does not exist
                ServiceClient<cop_save.Request, cop_save.Response, cop_save> client = n.serviceClient("/cop/save", new ros.pkg.vision_srvs.srv.cop_save());
                                                                                                                                              ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:294: package cop_save does not exist
                cop_save.Request rq = new cop_save().createRequest();
                        ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:294: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class cop_save
location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.ExportCopModelCallback
                cop_save.Request rq = new cop_save().createRequest();
                                          ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:302: package cop_save does not exist
                    cop_save.Response resp = client.call(rq);
                            ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:335: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable CommunicationVisApplet
location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.ExportCopModelCallback
                    CommunicationVisApplet.visualizeCommunication("", vis_string, null, null);
                    ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:342: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable CopROSClient
location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.ExportCopModelCallback
                    String[] model_info = CopROSClient.copModelTypeSemClassForID(req.object_id);
                                          ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:391: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable CommunicationVisApplet
location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.ExportCopModelCallback
                    CommunicationVisApplet.visualizeCommunication("", "Export of model for Cop ID "+req.object_id+" failed.", null, null);
                    ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:437: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable CommunicationVisApplet
location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.RetrieveCopModelCallback
                    CommunicationVisApplet.visualizeCommunication("Requesting model for object '"+req.object_name+"' from RoboEarth...", "", null, "roboearth.png");
                    ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:460: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable CommunicationVisApplet
location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.RetrieveCopModelCallback
                        CommunicationVisApplet.visualizeCommunication("", "Object model download finished.\n\n"+targetFolderFile.getName(), null, null);
                        ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:513: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable CommunicationVisApplet
location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.RetrieveCopModelCallback
                            CommunicationVisApplet.visualizeCommunication("Sending model for object '"+req.object_name+"' to the vision system...\n\n"+xmlFileName, "", null, "cop.png");
                            ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:523: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable CommunicationVisApplet
location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.RetrieveCopModelCallback
                            CommunicationVisApplet.visualizeCommunication("", "Object model "+xmlFileName+" received.", null, null);
                            ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:536: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable CommunicationVisApplet
location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.RetrieveCopModelCallback
                        CommunicationVisApplet.visualizeCommunication("", "No model for "+req.object_name+" found.", null, null);
                        ^
/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:548: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable CommunicationVisApplet
location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.RetrieveCopModelCallback
                CommunicationVisApplet.visualizeCommunication("", "No model for "+req.object_name+" found.", null, null);
                ^
19 errors
make[3]: *** [../bin/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.class] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_java_compile_1_53.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems re_comm cannot find those packages. How to fix that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68773/problem-compiling-re_comm/) by [HanXiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/5433/hanxiao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2013-07-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-07-30**:
Please mark your question as answered (click the checker sign next to the answer you like most), if your problems got resolved. Thank you

**Comment by [HanXiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/5433/hanxiao/) on 2013-07-30**:
Marked, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those packages are in the ias_common stack that you can (on Ubuntu) install using

sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-ias-common

To find out which repository a package is in, you can always use

roslocate uri vision_srvs

UPDATE: ias_common is no longer needed, please update the KnowRob stack to its new repository URL as given in the RoboEarth [rosinstall file](http://wiki.ros.org/roboearth_stack?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=roboearth.rosinstall) or on the KnowRob wiki page http://wiki.ros.org/knowrob.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-07-30**:
Woah, didn't know about this handy tool! Seems like there is always something one does *not* know about ROS! :-) Thanks for sharing!